# tf-idf document term matrix and LDA: Error messages in R

Tags: r, matrix, text-mining, lda, tidytext

Can we input tf-idf document term matrix into Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA)? if yes, how?

It does not work in my case and the LDA function requires the 'term-frequency' document term matrix.

Thank you

(I make a question as concise as possible. So, if you need more details, I can add

```
##########################################################################
                           TF-IDF Document matrix construction
##########################################################################    

> DTM_tfidf <-DocumentTermMatrix(corpora,control = list(weighting = 
function(x)+   weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE)))
> str(DTM_tfidf)
List of 6
$ i       : int [1:4466] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ j       : int [1:4466] 6 10 22 26 28 36 39 41 47 48 ...
$ v       : num [1:4466] 6 2.09 1.05 3.19 2.19 ...
$ nrow    : int 64
$ ncol    : int 297
$ dimnames:List of 2
  ..$ Docs : chr [1:64] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ Terms: chr [1:297] "accommod" "account" "achiev" "act" ...
- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "DocumentTermMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
- attr(*, "weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency - inverse document 
frequency" "tf-idf"

##########################################################################
                           LDA section
##########################################################################

> LDA_results <-LDA(DTM_tfidf,k, method="Gibbs", control=list(nstart=nstart,
  +                                seed = seed, best=best, 
  +                                burnin = burnin, iter = iter, thin=thin))

##########################################################################
                           Error messages
##########################################################################
  Error in LDA(DTM_tfidf, k, method = "Gibbs", control = list(nstart = 
  nstart,  : 
  The DocumentTermMatrix needs to have a term frequency weighting
```

Comment: It's best practice to provide a minimal reproducible example. You can do that by using a dummy data set or an example data set that comes with a package. (See e.g. my last answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explore the documentation for LDA topic modeling using the topicmodels package, for example by typing `?LDA` in the R console, you'll see that this modeling procedure is expecting a frequency-weighted document-term matrix, not tf-idf-weighted.

```
"Object of class "DocumentTermMatrix" with term-frequency weighting or an object coercible..."
```

So the answer is no, you cannot use a tf-idf-weighted DTM directly in this function. If you *have* a tf-idf-weighted DTM already, you can convert it using `tm::weightTf()` to get to the necessary weighting. If you are building a document-term matrix from scratch, then don't weight it by tf-idf.

Comment: Thank you .... I use 2 accounts because some time I have two irrelevant questions at the same time. I am not sure whether this may preach the rule of the forum or not.

Comment: As far as LDA is concerned, is it possible to weight the document term matrix and take some 0 weight terms out of the sparse matrix?

Comment: The purpose of this is to reduce the dimensionality of the matrix ( a function of TF-IDF here is like the stopword removal. Instead of removing the stop words, this removes words that occur too frequency and contribute little information to the corpus.  
 I have come across the link: http://davidmeza1.github.io/2015/07/20/topic-modeling-in-R.html

Comment: term_tfidf <- tapply(llistopic.dtm$v/slam::row_sums(llistopic.dtm)
           [llistopic.dtm$i], llistopic.dtm$j, mean) *
           log2(tm::nDocs(llistopic.dtm)/slam::col_sums(llistopic.dtm > 0))
                  summary(term_tfidf)


It is like we are manipulating the DTM ,but the computer still understands that the DTM is frequency-weight scheme.   @Julia